# Android Gridview data get lost while rotating

Tags: android, gridview, rotation

I am working on an app. In that, a gridview has 14 images. When I set rotation to 270 degrees and 90 degrees to image, then only 10 images are displayed at first position and few last images getting lost.

What I am missing here?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you in Advance.

This is xml code

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
```

this is adapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.add, R.drawable.camera_green,
            R.drawable.delete, R.drawable.flag_english,
            R.drawable.flag_dutch, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_checked, R.drawable.pin_enter,
            R.drawable.ic_relations_g, R.drawable.right_arrow,
            R.drawable.ic_overview_g, R.drawable.gallery,
            R.drawable.close_btn, R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("click item position", "" + position);
            }
        });
        return imageView;
    }
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: We would need to see some code. Your layout xml file and adapter code most likely.

Comment: xml file and adapter code are given plz reply

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, I'm confused as to what your problem is... You have a 2 column grid and you rotate it. What are you expecting to happen?